# Why is the Royal Road progression (IV-V-iii-vi) often resolved by a ii-V-I cadence?

Tags: chord-progressions

The IV-V-iii-vi progression is very often resolved by a ii-V-I cadence, making an extended progression of IV-V-iii-vi-ii-V-I which is very common in anime music. What's the reason?

Comment: The reason for what?

Comment: You might enjoy this video: [The history of the anime canon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvcRm4pPjvU).

Comment: Not only that sequence, but sooo many others!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is specific to the Royal Road progression, but if you look at the final chords after the IV–V motion, you realize this is just a big circle of fifths progression: iii–vi–ii–V–I.

This pattern is common in multiples styles of music, from classical to popular to non-Western, and likely because of this descending-fifth motion and its prevalence in (and connection to) tonal music.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest explanation is the most likely:

Because The [Royal Road progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IV%E2%96%B37%E2%80%93V7%E2%80%93iii7%E2%80%93vi_progression) ends on vi, and the ii-V-I cadence is among the most common ways in any kind of music (not just Anime) to get from vi to I.

Answer (score 2):

`IV V iii vi` and `ii V I` give you all the diatonic triads excluding the dissonant diminished triad `viio`.

`IV V iii vi` does not effect a cadence, it sort of works as a *deceptive progression*, but I think the really point is it give you diatonic chords with no closing, my suspicion is this progression repeats a lot in the music.

`ii V I` provides a standard cadence which is a closing.

It makes musical sense to follow the inconclusive `IV V iii vi` with a concluding `ii V I`, if you want music with a sense of beginning, middle, end structure.

Comment: Does the fact that ii is a fifth below vi make a difference, especially in choosing ii - V - I over IV - V - I?

Comment: Sure, it extends the descending fifths progression. But I don't how these two pieces may be repeated. If the first four chord repeat, the full descending fifths sequence is not as apparent.